# Linux Transparent Bridge for Network

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I am attempting to set up a semi-transparent bridge. I say semi because I want it to act as a transparent tap for all traffic moving through both sides of the bridge. What I also want is to have the "green zone" accessible to a web interface for the bridge that will display all results of the IDS and other network monitoring tools. My example would be as such:

`eth0 <--> bridge(br0) <--> eth1`

The entire network would be on the same subset however anything coming from eth0 to `eth1` would be accepted. The only time anything would be drop is if the `eth0` attempted to access `br0`. If someone attempts to access the web interface on `br0` through `eth1` it will succeed. My biggest problem I feel is if I attempt to block anything from `eth0` to `br0` this will drop the bridge all together.

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 --dport 80 -j DROP
```

Everything that's forwarded is handled by other chains, so if it's across the bridge it won't be affected. Those are handled by the FORWARD chain.

Here's a good [reference example](http://linuxexchange.org/questions/158/bridge-firewall-with-iptables-how-do-i-block-incoming-traffic-except-for-specified-ports-and-allow-outgoing-traffic).

Comment: As a quick followup question to this, what exactly am I trying to build at this point? It's not really a transparent bridge, but depending on where you are you shouldn't be able to see it either.

Comment: *what exactly am I trying to build at this point* I think you need to tell me that one. It sounds like you want a bridge that has an IP address and is accessible. This is basically a managed switch with 2 ports.

Answer (score 1):

So: `eth0=lan1` `eth1=lan2` `br0=briges both + has an IP that should be accessible by eth1 only` - right?

For iptables and birdges use the [`physdev`](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section6) module in iptables

> iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -d the.ip.on.br0 -m physdev --physdev-in eth0 -j DROP

would DROP connections to br0 when they came in via eth0 (or reverse and ACCEPT there, depends on your other rules)

Comment: This didn't work any ideas why something like:
`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p TCP --dport 80 -j DROP` wouldn't work either?

Comment: "didn't work"... i would need some more info... paste `ip addr`, `brctl show` and `iptables-save` please  |  the "-i eth0" @jeff suggested won´t work on a bridge [See Why](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section6) TL;DR: the 'join' happens before the packet reaches the kernel/iptables, so for iptables the "--input" would be br0